# Magento + APC + PHP-FPM crashes

Tags: magento, apc, php

I've set up Magento 1.8.1 with PHP 5.4 and APC 3.1.15 (all running on EC2 - AWS Linux).

Magento crashes intermittently (and frequently) with APC active.  I can't reproduce the issue with any specific area of the site; but going to various pages in the admin, I can get it to crash within five minutes.

According to the logs...

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot override final method Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::toHtml() in /var/www/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget.php on line 35
```

With APC off, the problem goes away (and performance sucks).  I've read everything I could find from Google searches, but nothing specific to this issue.  All the issues seem to be about memory consumption (adjusting shared memory, etc).  It's not a segfault or out of memory error.

Anyone have any insight into this error?

Comment: Turn off compilation and re-compile.

Comment: Turning off compilation and re-compiling once appears to have fixed the issue with my Magento setups.